# Clashes when merging two C projects

Tags: c, merging, typedef

I am starting a new project, which will take two existing projects, use part of the functionality of each, and will add new functionality.

As usual, both projects don't use standard C types, preferring to `typedef` their own.

All code is in C, not C++, so obviously, both projects wanted a boolean type, and both have typedef'd `Bool`, resulting in a compiler error in the new code when it includes both header files (the existing projects know nothing of each other & build just fine).

Obviously, neither team wants to change their code (and potentially destabilize it).

And there is no `#if typedef`.

Bad ascii art follows:

```
-------------       ---------------       -------------
| Project X |       | new project |       | Project Y |
-------------       ---------------       -------------
          \           /           \         /
           \         /             \       /
       ----------------           -------------- 
       |    X.h       |           |    Y.h     |
       ----------------           --------------
```

Where both x.h and y.h `typedef` Bool.

I need to be able to build the existing projects X and Y, plus the new project.

How can I get around the problem of the double definition in the new project (which needs lots of other stuff from x.h and y.h), and still be able to build the existing projects X and Y?

(Note: the problem may be more than just `Bool`, but that's the first one that crops up, so I use it as an example. I am hoping not to find two functions or enums with the same name).

I am looking for a solution which, preferably, has no impact on existing code, or has minimal impact on existing code. I do have an idea in mind, but would prefer to hear from others, preferably someone who has done this before.

Comment: The problem with `Bool` is that you're trying to use the conflicting definitions in the same compilation unit. You can avoid that by introducing an adapter for each dependency. I.e. the new project would depend on an X-Adapter which defines a clean `X_Adapter.h`. Then only `X_Adapter.c` would include the problematic `X.h`, thus isolating your project. Yes, this does require you to basically repeat all function declarations in the new header. And it doesn't protect you from linker errors, though you can possibly get around that via dynamic linking.

Comment: You are probably looking for how to simulate namespaces in C. When you google for these keywords, you find some solutions, for example this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389827/namespaces-in-c. The `Bool` problem, however, might be solved in a simpler manner, if both `typedefs` use the same underlying type like `int` or `char`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if your first problem is name clashes.

If both projects did indeed define the expected types in the expected way, then it might be enough to simply `#undef` the clashing macro immediately before it is `#define`'d in both places. If they did subtly different things with it, then this could introduce subtle defects; but I think in that case you won't get away without diving into both code bases anyway.

Comment: The problem is that these are not `#define`, but `typedef`

Answer (score 1):

You could create an "API" project where you move all the duplicated typedefs to and have project X and project Y using that.

Comment: I *could", but they are extremely resistant to change, as they don't want their projects destabilized. Nor do they want an expensive full retest

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about:

```
#define Bool X_Bool
#include "X.h"
#undef Bool
#define Bool Y_Bool
#include "Y.h"
#undef Bool
```

It's not what I would call maintainable or sensible use of the preprocessor, but it works in your case.

Comment: The problem is that there exist two `typedef`s, and 1) they don't want to use #define, 2) neither even wants to change their code

Comment: https://gist.github.com/krypt-n/c7c104fd30a5efd49fbf836d072a9d39 1) no additional define in X or Y 2) no changed code in X or Y